# View options gone from post edit history?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, revisions-list

Various options have disappeared from the post revision history (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15029122/revisions)).

I found it very useful to be able to see side-by-side diffs, markdown diffs *and* the inline diffs that we're stuck on now.

Please put the options back. There is no reason that I can see to remove them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those options are still there, *provided the [post body was edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15026105/revisions)*.

The diffs have never been available for edits that just change the title or the tags. The example you linked to only added tags.

Comment: Dammit SO GUI stop confusing the heck out of me! I'm an _experienced_ user of interfaces and it shouldn't be possible to confuse me with one this much.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Meh it is Friday. We all tend to have our issues focusing before the weekend. :)

Comment: @JoshMein: I've been on sabbatical for two months, so that's not it. I am blaming the inconsistent GUI.